# Session Id changes in Django POST response

Tags: python, django, rest, backend, session-hijacking

While doing a POST request we've noticed that the user and data were changed.
in the dev tools we saw the the `session_id` that came back from the server was different from the request.

What can cause such a behavior? we are using Django 1.6

[image]

Comment: It alters the expiration of the session?

Comment: Although not an answer: you should really upgrade to at least Django-1.11, since the previous versions are no longer supported: https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the session is still valid, we are slow in upgrading, we know

Comment: yes, but the session itself has an expiration value at the end, and that is incremented to avoid expiration.